# Ошибка при создании NSString в switch

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Почему при создании объекта NSString в блоке switch компилятор выдает ошибку *"Expected expression"*?

```
switch (a) {
        case 1:
            NSString *f;   //Expected expression
            break;   
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Засуньте тело внутри `case 1:` в операторные скобки

```
  switch (a) {
        case 1:
           {//<---
            NSString *f;   //Expected expression
            break;
           }//<---
        default:
            break;
    }
```